# Transitions between activities with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm making transitions between activities using `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`. I create custom `Transitions` programmatically and set them using `window.enterTransition` and `window.exitTransition`.
My activities stack looks like this:

```
A (transition1) ---> B1 (transition2) ---> B2
```

Now I want to return from `B2` to `A` with `transition1` as if I return from `B1`. So I want to clear activities stack with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and bring `A` to front. Unfortunally, exit animation of `B2` is not working, activity `A` is just started with default animation.
I attached listener to see if `exitTransition` is started, and seems like it is started but being cancelled after some time. Also, I tried to start Activity `A` without flag just to check if I set transitions up correctly, and everything works fine.

So it seems that when I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, Activity `B2` is being finished without `exitTransition`. Has anyone faced similar issues? I know, I can finish `B1` before starting `B2` and then, instead of starting A with `CLEAR_TOP` I can just finish `B2`. But that's just so unconvinient and dirty, since I had to manage enter, return, reenter etc. transitions between `B1` and `B2` manually so I want to make sure there are no other solution.

I also saw solutions with `overridePendingTransitions`. These are not suitable, since this method allows to use only transitions defined in xml, but I have custom transitions, that can be setup only programmatically.